# Remove $PATH entry based on regex

Tags: regex, perl, shell, replace

I'm trying to remove an entry in $PATH if that entry contains a given string `foo`.  For example `PATH=/home/me/bin:/home/foo/bin:/usr/foo/bin:/bin` would become `PATH=/home/me/bin:/bin`.  I currently have

```
echo $PATH | perl -pe 's/:(.*?)foo(.*?):/:/g'
```

but this seems to be removing too many entries, even though I'm trying to use non-greedy matching.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As for the greediness: That regex will still match *the first* `:` and then everything up to `foo`. The non-greediness in this case only means it will not match any `foo`s on the way. You might want to change `(.*?)` to `[^:]*` to explicitly not include any colons (not sure what the capturing group was for).

Comment: ...moreover, that regex won't work if the `foo` entry is the first or last (without a colon before and/or after). Using just `[^:]*` on either side should solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `awk` to loop through the paths, printing just the ones that don't contain `foo`:

```
awk -F: '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /foo/) {printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF? RS : FS)}}'
```

#### Explanation

- `-F:` sets `:` as field separator.
- `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)` loop through the fields.
- `if ($i !~ /foo/)` if the path does not contain the string `foo`, then perform next action:
- `printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF? RS : FS)` print the line, ending with new line or `:` depending on the position it is. If it is the last field, new line; otherwise, `:`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
/home/me/bin:/home/foo/bin:/usr/foo/bin:/bin
/home/me/bin:/home/fio/bin:/usr/foo/bin:/bin

$ awk -F: '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /foo/) {printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF? RS : FS)}}' a
/home/me/bin:/bin
/home/me/bin:/home/fio/bin:/bin
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know the reason of the downvote. Feel free to explain so I can check some inaccuracies.

Comment: For what it's worth, the awk command worked just fine for me, and you provided a detailed explanation for those that are curious.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

I would split the string, select the valid parts and then join the string again:

```
perl -e 'print join ":", grep !/foo/, split ":", $ENV{PATH}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
perl -pe 's/:(.*?)foo[^:]*(?=:|$)//g' <<< "$PATH"
/home/me/bin:/bin
```

Comment: This still removes entries erroneously.  Also, out of interest, what does the triple left chevron do?

Comment: This removes 2 paths containing `foo`, why is that wrong and what is your expected output?

Comment: My actual path is somewhat longer and, when I tried your regex, it still removed some entries preceding the matching entry.

Comment: It worked with the provided data. If it is not working for certain case, please provide the input data with your expected output and I will investigate.

Comment: As an unexperienced regex user who wants to learn: What does the `?=:` do?

Comment: I made a change. `(?=:|$)` is a positive lookahead that makes sure input should be followed by a colon or end of input.

Answer (score 0):

I started to construct a regex that would deal with all the combinations of colons at either end, but it got complex fast. But since you're using Perl (good choice BTW) how about something like:

```
perl -e 'print join(":", grep { $_ !~ m/foo/ } split( ":", '"$PATH"' ) );'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good of you to use non-greedy matching `.*?` in your below regex.

```
echo $PATH | perl -pe 's/:(.*?)foo(.*?):/:/g'
```

However, there is a flaw in your regex because you did not limit the allowed characters, and therefore it can capture across your colon boundaries.

That's one reason why `split` is a nice tool.  It not only enforces boundaries but also the accepted characters between them.

It's of course possible to do this using a regex though, like you intended:

```
echo $PATH | perl -pe 's/[^:=]*foo[^:]*:?//g'
```

The above will leave a trailing colon if it's the last entry.